# Any better way to fine tune the code?

Tags: powershell

I am a newbie programming. I need to write a script like the following.

```
# { ---A ---}
# define N task object, N is dynamically generated
$task1 = {commandA $p1}
...
$taskN = {commandA $pN}

# { ---B ---}
# if there is N task, it will have N jobs
$job1 = Start-Job -ScriptBlock $task1 
...
$jobN = Start-Job -ScriptBlock $taskN 

# { ---C ---}
# Feed those N job to wait-job 
$null = Wait-Job -Job $job1,$job2,...,$jobN

# { ---D ---}
$result1 = Receive-Job -Job $job1
...
$result15 = Receive-Job -Job $jobN

# { ---E ---}
Remove-Job -Job $job1,$job2,...,$jobN
```

Originally I plan to use a loop to write section "A,B and D" because I don't want to copy and paste N times. However, I don't know how to feed those object in section C and E if I use a loop because N is dynamically generated. It will be great if you could provide some hints.

Comment: Please describe what your script should do - maybe there's a completely different and much better way than what you imagine.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Swonkie that you'd be getting better answers if you described the actual problem you're trying to solve instead of describing what you perceive as the solution.

However, to answer your immediate question, you would organize your tasks in a list:

```
$tasks = @()
$tasks += {commandA $p1}
...
$tasks += {commandA $pN}
```

Once you have this list you can process it with a loop to start the individual jobs, and collect them in another list that you can use for further processing:

```
$jobs = $tasks | ForEach-Object {
          Start-Job -ScriptBlock $_
        }

Wait-Job -Job $jobs | Out-Null

$results = @()
$jobs | ForEach-Object {
  $results += Receive-Job -Job $_
}

Remove-Job -Job $jobs
```